# Pseudo force and Potential energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

The pseudo force equation is

$$\vec F_p=-2\,m\,(\vec \omega\times \vec v)-m\,(\vec\omega\times (\vec\omega\times \vec R))$$

where $~\vec v=\dot{\vec{R}}$ and $~\vec\omega=\text{const.}$

the  pseudo force is depending on the generalized coordinates  $~\vec q~$ and the generalized velocities $~\dot{\vec{q}}$

If we applied the Euler-Lagrange  to obtain the equations of motion, the pseudo force is external force , but instead we   can use potential energy with this Lagrange function

$$\mathcal{L}(~\vec q~,~\dot{\vec{q}})=\frac m2\,\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}-U_p\\
U_p=m\,(\vec\omega\times\vec v)\cdot \vec R-\frac m2 (\vec\omega\times\vec R)\cdot (\vec\omega\times\vec R)$$

my question is  what is the mathematical derivation to obtain the pseudo force potential $~U_p$?

Comment: What sort of derivation are you looking for, except the proof that this potential indeed reproduces the correct equations of motion as its E-L equations? We usually don't "derive" Lagrangians or Hamiltonians, really - their entire justification lies in reproducing the correct equations of motion

Comment: @ACuriousMind how you obtain the equation of the potential energy ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Potential for a general fictitious force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498165/2451)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a general method to find $U_p$, but it must satisfy (using $x,y,z$ as generalized coordinates) $$\vec{F}_p=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{v}}U_p\right)-\vec\nabla U_p$$or, in components,
$$\left(\vec{F_{p}}\right)_i=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial U_p}{\partial v_i}\right)-\frac{\partial U_p}{\partial x_i}.\tag{1}$$

You could try a solution in the form (repeated indices are summed from $1$ to $3$)$$U_p=A_{ijk}~\omega_i~v_j~x_k~+~B_{ijkl}~\omega_i~\omega_j~x_k~x_l~+...\tag{2}$$ where $x_i$ are the components of the vector $\vec{R}.$

Note that since the force does not depend on the acceleration, the generalized potential may depend at most linearly on the velocity. You can add terms to $(2)$ using arguments like this.

More notes:

- The components of the force are (repeated indices are summed) $$\left(\vec{F_{p}}\right)_i=-2m~\epsilon_{ijk}~\omega_j~v_k-m~\epsilon_{ijk}~\omega_j~\epsilon_{kab}~\omega_a~x_b$$
- By construction, $B_{ijkl}=B_{jikl}=B_{jilk}$.

Comment: so you have to solve partial differential equations to obtain the solution for $U_p$ ?

Comment: Well, that's an option, trying to solve $(1)$ for $U_p(\vec{R},\vec{v})$, but that may be very difficult. The option I recommend is trying a solution in the form of $(2)$, where $A_{ijk},B_{ijkl},...$ are constants, so you can introduce it into $(1)$ and algebraically find those constants.

Comment: In general the position vector R is a function of the generalized coordinates in this case Eq (1) is not valid , you can’t say you have 3 components

Comment: It is true that in general the generalized force is $$Q_i=\vec{F}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial q_i},$$ so the generalized potential must satisfy $$Q_i=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{q}_i}\right)-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}.$$ I assumed that you were using $x,y,z$ as generalized coordinates, and in that case these two expressions reduce to the ones in my answer.