# Does there exist a Coriolis potential, just like there is a Centrifugal potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, potential, coriolis-effect

While dealing with central force there is a known result:
$$U_\text{eff}(r)=\frac{L^2}{2m r^2}+ U(r) \, $$

If I understand correctly the centrifugal potential term $l^2/(2\mu r^2)$ arises when you look at an orbit from $(r,\theta)$ perspective and just look at it in one dimension $r$. Is there also a coriolis potential that you can derive in a similar fashion? How would you interpret that?

Comment: What would a velocity-dependent “potential” look like?

Comment: I guess a vector potential

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Potential for a general fictitious force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498165/2451)

Answer (score 5):

Your guess in the comment seems correct: one can introduce a vector potential for the Coriolis force (American Journal of Physics 41, 585 (1973); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1987297 , or https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.11359 )

Answer (score 4):

The coriolis term in the equation of motion for a rotating coordinate system is proportional to velocity.

The convention is to define a potential when at each point in space the force exterted (for instance gravitational force) is a function of the position coordinate.

As we know: the potential difference between point A and point B is the negative of the work done in moving a test mass from point A to point B.

That is what allows the concept of centrifugal potential to be defined.

In the case of the coriolis term:
As we know: the coriolis term vector is *perpendicular* to the instantaneous velocity.

The definition of *work done* is displacement in the direction *parallel* to the force exerted.

That is: if a force is always acting perpendicular to the instantaneous velocity vector then the effect of that force does not fall in the category of *work done*.

As we know: the coriolis term vector is perpendicular to the instantaneous velocity.